# Как правильно реализовать переходы между страницами без обновления на ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть шаблон одного проекта, хотелось бы получить совет от профи. Как правильно реализовать переход между блоками без перезагрузки страницы и без лишней нагрузки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пример 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пример 2

Ранее я реализовал что то подобное, и каждую страницу выгружал GET запросом через ajax JS. Но это я на ходу придумал, и думаю что не правильно сделал. Если вам не трудно, можете здесь оставить полезный материал. Я даже не знаю как это искать.

Comment: В качестве вводной части, думаю, стоит почитать, что такое Single Page Application (SPA) - одностраничное приложение. Для реализации такого рода приложений уже существуют готовые инструменты (Vue, React и другие), которые позволяют организовать приложение в том плане "правильно", о котором вы бы хотели узнать.

P.S. Не профи, но, кажется, что-то знаю

Comment: Может пора окунуться в мир SPA (одностраничных приложений)... https://thecode.media/spa/

Comment: Или разбивать страницу на фреймы... И менять только нужное содержание соответствующего фрейма... https://www.wm-school.ru/html/html_frame.html

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, действительно очень полезная информация